# Maven - Allure Report generation issue

Tags: xml, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, allure

I have a cucumber-maven-allure framework.

I run the test suite via the Maven command line by passing parameters in `systemPropertyVariables`

Both HTML and JSON reports are getting generated, but Build status is failing with the below error:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-06T18:45:29+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 97M/678M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) on project DI_Cucumber_BDD: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site: org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.7.1/maven-site-plugin-3.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-exec/1.4/maven-reporting-exec-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.1.0/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.1.1/maven-archiver-3.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/3.4/plexus-archiver-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.7.1/plexus-io-2.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.11/commons-compress-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-10/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.8/doxia-sink-api-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.8/doxia-logging-api-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.8/doxia-module-xhtml-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.8/doxia-core-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.2/httpclient-4.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.8/doxia-module-apt-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.8/doxia-module-xdoc-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.8/doxia-module-fml-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-markdown/1.8/doxia-module-markdown-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-all/0.18.4/flexmark-all-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark/0.18.4/flexmark-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-abbreviation/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-abbreviation-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-anchorlink/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-anchorlink-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-aside/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-aside-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-autolink/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-autolink-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/nibor/autolink/autolink/0.6.0/autolink-0.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-definition/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-definition-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-emoji/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-emoji-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-escaped-character/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-escaped-character-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-footnotes/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-footnotes-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-gfm-tables/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-gfm-tables-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-gfm-tasklist/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-gfm-tasklist-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-jekyll-front-matter/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-jekyll-front-matter-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-jekyll-tag/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-jekyll-tag-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-ins/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-ins-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-xwiki-macros/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-xwiki-macros-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-spec-example/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-spec-example-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-test-util/0.18.4/flexmark-test-util-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-superscript/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-superscript-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-tables/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-tables-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-toc/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-toc-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-typographic/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-typographic-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-wikilink/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-wikilink-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-ext-yaml-front-matter/0.18.4/flexmark-ext-yaml-front-matter-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-formatter/0.18.4/flexmark-formatter-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-html-parser/0.18.4/flexmark-html-parser-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.10.2/jsoup-1.10.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-jira-converter/0.18.4/flexmark-jira-converter-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-pdf-converter/0.18.4/flexmark-pdf-converter-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-core/0.0.1-RC9/openhtmltopdf-core-0.0.1-RC9.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-pdfbox/0.0.1-RC9/openhtmltopdf-pdfbox-0.0.1-RC9.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.4/pdfbox-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/fontbox/2.0.4/fontbox-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-rtl-support/0.0.1-RC9/openhtmltopdf-rtl-support-0.0.1-RC9.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/58.1/icu4j-58.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-jsoup-dom-converter/0.0.1-RC9/openhtmltopdf-jsoup-dom-converter-0.0.1-RC9.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-profile-pegdown/0.18.4/flexmark-profile-pegdown-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-util/0.18.4/flexmark-util-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/com/vladsch/flexmark/flexmark-youtrack-converter/0.18.4/flexmark-youtrack-converter-0.18.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.8.1/doxia-decoration-model-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.8.1/doxia-site-renderer-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-skin-model/1.8.1/doxia-skin-model-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.2/plexus-velocity-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-tools/2.0/velocity-tools-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-integration-tools/1.8.1/doxia-integration-tools-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.25/jetty-6.1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.25/jetty-util-6.1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[86] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[87] = file:/C:/Users/Test.User/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Please find the POM below,

```xml
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>TestBDD</groupId>
        <artifactId>TestBDD</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <!-- Needed for allure-maven-plugin to specify report version -->
            <allure.version>1.5.2</allure.version>
            <aspectj.version>1.8.4</aspectj.version>
        </properties>


        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--<forkMode>never</forkMode>-->
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/${testSuite}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                            -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter
                        </argLine>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <project>${project}</project>
                            <env_HostName>${env_HostName}</env_HostName>
                            <ambari_HostName>${ambari_HostName}</ambari_HostName>
                            <browserName>${browserName}</browserName>
                            <executionType>${executionType}</executionType>
                            <seleniumHub>${seleniumHub}</seleniumHub>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-descriptor</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>MyProjectName</projectName>  <!-- Replace with project name -->
                                <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                                <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports/jsonreport.json</cucumberOutput>
                                <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                                <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.14.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
                <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
                <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20170516</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.1212</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0.201409260305-r</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.54</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ca.krasnay</groupId>
                <artifactId>sqlbuilder</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.dzieciou.testing</groupId>
                <artifactId>curl-logger</artifactId>
                <version>0.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
                <version>2.26</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
                <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0_05</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
                <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-reporting-exec</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>

        <reporting>
            <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <resultsDirectory>allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                        <allureDownloadUrl>
                            https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure2.7.0.zip
                        </allureDownloadUrl>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </project>
```

If I run `mvn install` by passing parameter directly in `systemPropertyVariables`, the build passes. When running via the Maven command line, the build fails, but reports are generated.

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but PDFBox is at 2.0.17.

Comment: Hi,could you please elloborate PDFBOX is at 2.0.17 ?

Comment: That is the version number. It is a good practice to use the latest versions of libraries.